# Spanning trees on disconnected graphs

Tags: graphs, minimum-spanning-tree

Can anyone please help me out with my query: can disconnected graphs have minimum spanning trees?

Comment: Hint: what the word "spanning" stands for ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, because by definition trees are connected. However, one might talk about *spanning forests* when referring to a collection of trees each of which is a spanning tree of some disconnected graph.

Wikipedia has some [discussion on spanning forests](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spanning_tree#Spanning_forests) and related definitions.

Answer (score 1):

A spanning tree, by definition, has the same vertices as the graph it spans. Since such a tree is an [induced subgraph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glossary_of_graph_theory_terms#induced) and, since trees are (by definition) connected, the graph itself must be connected.

Note this applies to any spanning tree, not just a minimal one (i.e., an MST).